# Eloquent JS: Electronic Life project question

Tags: javascript

For those who have read the book here is the code in question: https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/code/chapter/07_elife.js
(read till View.prototype.find).
Question: in World.prototype.letAct why do we check the object action, dest for null in the if statements. The same thing happens in World.prototype.checkDestination in `if(directions.hasOwnProperty(action.direction)`. action object that is returned by BouncingCritter.prototype.act will be an object no matter what right? Or am i missing something?